# How to add OrderBy to the Query result in ORCHARD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

how to add `OrderBy(a=>a.SortField)` or sort the below query result by "SortField"

```
var slideShowProducts = _contentManager.Query<JewelleryProductPart, JewelleryProductPartRecord>("JewelleryProduct")
                .Join<CustomPropertiesPartRecord>()
                .Where(cpp => cpp.CustomOne == catViewModel.Number)
                .Join<BodyPartRecord>()
                    .List()                                               
                    .Select(sp => new SlideShowProductViewModel
                    {

                        Count = sp.Count,
                        CategoryName = sp.Fields.Single(f => f.PartFieldDefinition.Name == "Category").Storage.Get<string>(""),
                        SortField = sp.Fields.Single(f => f.PartFieldDefinition.Name == "Sort Field").Storage.Get<string>(""),
                        Description = sp.Get<BodyPart>().Text
                    }).ToList();


                SlideShowProductsViewModel products = new SlideShowProductsViewModel();
                products.Number = catViewModel.Number;
                products.CategoryName = catViewModel.Name;
                products.SlideShowProducts = slideShowProducts;                  


                productList.Add(products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
products.SlideShowProducts =slideShowProducts.OrderBy(a=>a.SortField).ToList();
```

Comment: If it's a field that probably won't work. Projections can order on fields. A better guess would probably to go look at the code in Orchard.Projections.